# SMTPSendFailedException 530 in Gmail , SMTP fails whereas IMAP works

Tags: java, authentication, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a sample gmail client class. In that class I initialize BOTH IMAPS & SMTPS sessions.
For some time it was working fine. But now Gmail throws SMTO Send Fail Exception.

Here is how I connect to Gmail via javamail..

```
//String smtpHost = "imap.gmail.com";
//String imapHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
//String userName = "XXXXXX@gmail.com";
//String userPass = "PASSWORD";
//Properties props = new Properties();


public DirectMailBox(String smtpHost, String imapHost, String userName,
        String userPass, Properties props) throws MessagingException {
    super();
    this.imapHost = imapHost;
    this.smtpHost = smtpHost;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userPass = userPass;
    this.props = props;

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(true);
    imapsStore = session.getStore("imaps");
    imapsStore.connect(imapHost, userName, userPass);

    smtpsTransport = session.getTransport("smtps");
    smtpsTransport.connect(smtpHost, userName, userPass);
    smtpsTransport.addTransportListener(this);
}
```

and here is how I call sendmail..

```
public void sendMail(MimeMessage newMessage) throws MessagingException {
    smtpsTransport.sendMessage(newMessage, newMessage.getAllRecipients());
}
```

Followed Instructions on this URL but no solution.
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257

Here is a debug Dump.....

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 14.140.225.250 uy8if8067087pbc.8
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! uy8if8067087pbc.8
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=XXXXXX@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
A1 LOGIN XXXXXX@gmail.com PASSWORD
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
A1 OK XXXXXX@gmail.com Rakesh Waghela authenticated (Success)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 mx.google.com ESMTP mt9sm3371719pbb.14
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "imap.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO LPT0031
250-mx.google.com at your service, [14.140.225.250]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 14.140.225.250 vf8if4407540pbc.7
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! vf8if4407540pbc.7
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=XXXXXX@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
A1 LOGIN XXXXXX@gmail.com PASSWORD
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
A1 OK XXXXXX@gmail.com Rakesh Waghela authenticated (Success)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ru4sm3359950pbc.66
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "imap.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO LPT0031
250-mx.google.com at your service, [14.140.225.250]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<RakeshW@LPT0031>
530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 mt9sm3371719pbb.14
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 mt9sm3371719pbb.14

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
    at com.wellogic.phoenix.mail.direct.DirectMailBox.sendMail(DirectMailBox.java:86)
    at com.wellogic.phoenix.test.DirectMailTest.testSendMail(DirectMailTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Not Delivered...
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: @HectorLector It's not like I am not able to connect..!! It's that im not able to send a mail...!!! IMAP woks on same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally resolved  the issue..!! Using following method.

http://mlusincuba.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/java-mail-gmail-smtp-client/

```
package com.mycompany.employee.utils;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 * @author Mlungisi
 *
 */
public class GMail {

    public static void sendMail(String senderEmail, String recipientEmail, String subject, String message) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // SSL // I USED THIS METHOD            
        Properties propsSSL = new Properties();

        // EVEN IF YOU SKIP THESE TWO PROP IT WOULD WORK
        propsSSL.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        propsSSL.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

        // THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT PROP --> "mail.smtps.auth"
        propsSSL.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

        Session sessionSSL = Session.getInstance(propsSSL);
        sessionSSL.setDebug(true);

        Message messageSSL = new MimeMessage(sessionSSL);
        messageSSL.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yourgmail@gmail.com", "Mlungisi Sincuba"));
        messageSSL.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("yourgmail@gmail.com")); // real recipient
        messageSSL.setSubject("Test mail using SSL");
        messageSSL.setText("This is test email sent to Your account using SSL.");

        Transport transportSSL = sessionSSL.getTransport();
        // EVEN IF YOU SKIP PORT NUMBER , IT WOULD WORK
        transportSSL.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, "yourgmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword"); // account used
        transportSSL.sendMessage(messageSSL, messageSSL.getAllRecipients());
        transportSSL.close();

        System.out.println("SSL done.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        sendMail(null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link that you mentioned not found ! can please find what is wrong in this method? dl.dropbox.com/u/3092259/TestJavaMail.zip  I'm getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using imap.gmail.com as your smtp server. You also might want to try turning smtp auth on.